# How to show/hide a div section when an ui:inputSelect is changed?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm creating like this for example:

```
<div class="divfield">
<ui:inputSelect aura:id="Select1" change="{!c.someAction}" class="slds-select" value="{!v.SomeSetting.list__c}" options="{!v.someMethodOption}"/></div>
<div id="section1" ><p>some fields are in here</p></div>
<div id="section2" ><p>other fields are in here</p></div>
```

if section1 is selected from the ui:inputSelect, the div section1 shows up and hides when it is not selected... how are we going to write this in the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Aura: if to show/hide a specific div

```
 <aura:attribute name="section1Val" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

<aura:attribute name="section2Val" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

   <div class="divfield">



     <ui:inputSelect aura:id="Select1" change="{!c.someAction}" class="slds-select" value="{!v.SomeSetting.list__c}" options="{!v.someMethodOption}"/>
      </div>

      <aura:if isTrue="{!v.section1Val}">
       <div id="section1" ><p>some fields are in here</p>
       </div>
      </aura:if>

      <aura:if isTrue="{!v.section2Val}">
       <div id="section2" ><p>other fields are in here</p>
       </div>
      </aura:if>


    component controller:

    ({
        someAction: function(c, e, h){
      c.set("v.section1Val",true);
      c.set("v.section2Val",true);
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thank you Ajay. I added a few lines on your controller sample though:

Comment: Thank you Ajay. I added a few lines on your controller sample though:                     
 var selected = component.find("Select1").get("v.value");        
        if(selected == 'section1value'){
            component.set("v.SelectedGlobal",true);
        }else{component.set("v.SelectedGlobal",false);}
        
        if(selected == 'section2value'){
            component.set("v.SelectedGAU",true); 
        }else{component.set("v.SelectedGAU",false); }